# How to add a quote between table rows without ending a block

Tags: tables, multirow

I need to add a centering plain text between tabular without ending tabular block. Now I have following code:

```
    ...
\begin{tabular}{p{0.3\linewidth}|p{0.6\linewidth}}
        Planet suihfsdhfh sohdfs9dh sdoifjis jdfsjdfo & Features\\[5pt]
        Mercury & Lunar like crust, crustal faulting, small magnetic
        fields.\\
\end{tabular}   
        \begin{quote}
            \centering
            \Large\textit{(action)}
        \end{quote}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.3\linewidth}|p{0.6\linewidth}}
        Jupiter & Covered by clouds, dark ring of dust, magnetic field.\\
        Saturn & Several cloud layers, magnetic field, thousands
        of rings.\\
        Uranus & Layers of cloud and mist, magentic field, some rings.\\
        Neptune & Unable to detect from earth.\\
        Pluto & Unable to detect from earth \\
\end{tabular}
```

> But I want to have something like this:

```
[![...
\begin{tabular}{p{0.3\linewidth}|p{0.6\linewidth}}
    Planet suihfsdhfh sohdfs9dh sdoifjis jdfsjdfo & Features\\\[5pt\]
    Mercury & Lunar like crust, crustal faulting, small magnetic
    fields.\\
    \begin{quote}
        \centering
        \Large\textit{(action)}
    \end{quote}
    Jupiter & Covered by clouds, dark ring of dust, magnetic field.\\
    Saturn & Several cloud layers, magnetic field, thousands
    of rings.\\
    Uranus & Layers of cloud and mist, magentic field, some rings.\\
    Neptune & Unable to detect from earth.\\
    Pluto & Unable to detect from earth \\
\end{tabular}   
\end{document}
```

[image: Here is example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `\multicolumn` to merge the two columns and get rid of the line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.3\linewidth}|p{0.6\linewidth}}
  Planet suihfsdhfh sohdfs9dh sdoifjis jdfsjdfo & Features\\[5pt]
  Mercury & Lunar like crust, crustal faulting, small magnetic
  fields.\\
  \multicolumn{2}{p{0.9\linewidth}}{%
    \begin{quote}
      \centering
      \Large\textit{(action)}
    \end{quote}
  }\\
  Jupiter & Covered by clouds, dark ring of dust, magnetic field.\\
  Saturn & Several cloud layers, magnetic field, thousands
  of rings.\\
  Uranus & Layers of cloud and mist, magentic field, some rings.\\
  Neptune & Unable to detect from earth.\\
  Pluto & Unable to detect from earth \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]